# Настроить консоль phpStorm, чтобы были доступны unix-команды (как в Git bash)

Tags: windows, phpstorm, консоль, git-bash

Почему в *command line tool phpStorm* не работают команды `ls`, `pwd`, `mkdir` и др.?

В обычной `cmd` эти команды тоже не работают. Зато в консоли *git bash* работают. *php*, *git*, *composer* — работают везде. Но это, я так понимаю, потому что прописано в переменной `PATH`.

В чем отличие консольных утилит и как сделать так, чтобы команды работали?

Comment: потому что это команды unix систем. В git bash есть что то вроде их интерпретатора на windows, но не для всех команд.

Comment: Сделать чтоб работали - загуглите Cygwin

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек
Блин, где тут лайки ставить ))

Comment: @Darth Пожалуйста, перенесите ваш комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @ДеняДеня: вместо лайка вы можете принять данный вам ответ, он вполне верный. (галочка слева от вопроса).

Answer (score 14):

По-умолчанию терминалом для PhpStorm является стандартный терминал windows `cmd.exe`. Для того чтобы настроить в PhpStorm `bash` терминал нужно изменить соответствующую настройку:

[image: Phpstorm git bash terminal]

`-login` и `-i` нужны для загрузки конфигурационных файлов и включения интерактивного режима.

Терминал можно кастомизировать. Для этого в домашней директории `~` необходимо создать файл `.bash_profile`. К примеру:

```
#Алиасы команд
alias ls="ls -CF --color --show-control-chars"
alias ll='ls -l'
alias l='ls -CF'

#Алиасы для опечаток
alias cd..="cd .."
alias ..="cd .."
```

Comment: А вариант настройки, когда ставится Unix-like система не рассматривается? =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Две причины: `Visual Studio Community` и `Steam` :) А вообще я настроил `ConEmu`, `Git shell` и теперь у меня есть полноценная консоль. Остальное всё что надо установлено на Vagrant.

Answer (score 8):

[Официальная документация](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.2/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html?search=terminal) по настройке и использованию внедрённого локального терминала в PhpStorm. На русском не нашёл.

[image: Фрагмент официальной справки про важность кавычек при настройке внедрения локального терминала в PhpStorm.]

[image: Правильные действующие настройки локального терминала в PhpStorm.]

Answer (score 3):

У меня немного по-другому, путь к командному файлу:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<some_key>\git-cmd.exe
```

По этому пути в настройках терминала запустился git-овский.

Comment: Похоже, что вы не установили Git for Windows, а используете некий  PortableGit, поставляемый вместе с клиентом GitHub. Поэтому он находится в другом месте.